# Bootstrap Carousel Progress Bar Mobile Phone problem

Tags: javascript, carousel

I've add an horizontal progress Bar on my Boostrap Carousel that initialized when slide:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var percent = 0,
    interval = 40,
    $bar = $('.myCarouselProgressBar'),
    $crsl = $('#myCarousel');
    $('.carousel-indicators li, .carousel-control').click(function (){$bar.css({width: 0.5 + '%'});});
    $crsl.carousel({
        interval: false,
        pause: true
    }).on('slide.bs.carousel', function () {percent = 0;});
    function progressBarCarousel() {
        $bar.css({width: percent + '%'});
        percent = percent + 0.5;
        if (percent >= 100) {
            percent = 0;
            $crsl.carousel('next');
        }
    }
    var barInterval = setInterval(progressBarCarousel, interval);
    if (!(/Mobi/.test(navigator.userAgent))) 
    {
      $crsl.hover(function(){clearInterval(barInterval);},
      function(){barInterval = setInterval(progressBarCarousel, interval);}
                );
    }
});
```

On desktop it's ok, but on mobile progress stop about 60% and slide next image, then view time it's slow too

Comment: I've put some alert and bar width it's 100% on desktop and mobile, but if I put alert before invoke carousel next only on desktop I see them correctly 100%, on mobile I don't see any alert but go to next image...why? who invoke next function?

Comment: I've try to put option data-interval="12000"  that for mobile it's same time that my function calc. Then function design bar but next event is called by bootstrap...it's not correct but works same desktop version